# How do I get more skill points than normal?

Tags: borderlands-2

Preferably without involving direct game files modification. I know Borderlands 2 save editor, but a downside to it is that any extra unspent skill points added are removed, presumably down to how many one should have. Optimally, I have exactly enough skill points to max out everything, and no more. I have heard of [the character switch glitch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116050/46216) which is typically instructed involving split-screen, but I play on PC.

Comment: If you max out every skill, you're done, why do you still need skillpoints then?

Comment: I don't need skillpoints then. I don't see your point?

Comment: I think the question is underspecified. Do you mean "how do I add exactly 33 points, so that when I hit level 72 I've got just enough points to max everything out?" Or do you mean "how do I add enough points to master everything now, and have the game stop giving me more points?" (33 may be the wrong number, I picked it out of a hat.)

Comment: Either way.4321

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did:

1) Use a Quick Change station to respec your character, so you have a large(-ish) number of unspent skill points.

2) Use Cheat Engine to find the location of unspent points in memory.

3) Lock the memory location while I added points to everything I wanted, then unlock it when I'm done.

(In theory, if the issue is "I don't want the game giving me any more points once I'm maxed out", you could keep Cheat Engine running after you're done with that value locked at 0.)